# How can I make tabular as compact as possible in width alignment

Tags: tables, tabularx

How can I make table compact as possible to remove space in between columns?

I have following example table:

```latex
\begin{document}
\begin{singlespace}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{cX}
        \toprule\addlinespace[0pt]
        \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Meaning} \\
        \noalign{\normalsize}
        \toprule\addlinespace[0pt]
          \noalign{\normalsize}
          \rowcolor{gray!25}
          $m$         & mad word    \\
          $s$         & sad word    \\
          \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{singlespace}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

### I believe there is 4 space in between or a `tab`.

The wanted output would be as 1. and 2. column as close to each other as possible with a single space in betwen:

[image]

Comment: the default tabcolsep is 12pt try `\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}` or whatever

Comment: If I have multiple tables one after another should I write `\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}` on top of each other? Seems like when I write it to the first table , it only applied to first table, but other tables remain unchanged

Comment: You can put it in the preamble, or right at the start of the document, in which case it should apply to all tables, unless you have other settings that would interfere. (Hard to tell since you didn't post a full example with documentclass and packages.) If you put it inside an environment, it'll only apply inside that environment.

Comment: What you should use is what David said. What you asked  is change `cX` by some like `{c@{~}X}`, that of course, will work only in that table. On the other hand,    `\tabcolsep` work only in your table because you placed jailed *inside* the `table` environment. Set it *before* `\begin{table}`  and then will be applied to all following tables.

Comment: If any of item's string is more than `Symbil`, `{c@{~}X}` cuts its longer section, but it was what I was looking for

Comment: @alper Sure? If you use a longer string, the `c` column will be also wider to avoid this, unless you are doing something odd to produce a wrong column width . E.g., replacing `$m$` to `very long content`  will produce a wider column, but  not `\makebox[1pt]{very long content}`, that will overlap the string with the second column. Change  the `~` spacer by `-` and probably  you will see that the string is simply close to the hyphen, but nothing is cut.  Note also that nothing prevent you to change  `~` to a bigger space  (`~~`,  `\quad`, `\qquad`, `\hspace{5em}` , etc.)  as needed.

Comment: Thanks , as I understand correctly, I could try: `~`, `~~`, `\quad`, `\qquad`, `\hspace{5em}`, `-` to see what works the best